# Visual Studio crashes while setting the modifier of base UserControl to protected

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, access-modifiers, visual-inheritance

I have a user control class `BaseUserControl` and a class `DerivedUserControl` which is derived from `BaseUserControl`. Both are shown correctly in the Visual Studio Designer, also after rebuilding the solution.

In the `BaseUserControl` I have a `protected` label and other `protected` controls. This label I wanted to hide for derived controls. So I searched for its name in the user code file as well as in the designer code file of `DerivedUserControl` for guaranteeing that it is not used by the `DerivedUserControl` and found no occurrences.
Then I set the modifier of this label in the designer of `BaseUserControl` from `protected` to `private` for hiding it. I did not change any other control and no code file.

Then I rebuild the solution again and want to show the designer of `DerivedUserControl`. But now Visual Studio crashed.

Therefore I tried to solve the problem by resetting the label modifier per hand  to `protected` in the designer code file of `BaseUserControl`. But in spite of rebuilding Visual Studio still always crashes if I open the designer of `DerivedUserControl`.

I have Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 Version 11.0.61030.00 Update 4 and Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.5.50938.

Has anyone an idea for solving this problem?

Comment: What error do you get? do you mean visual studio crashes or your program crashes?

Comment: Visual Studio crashes without any exact error message. "Visual Studio does not function." Then it want to restart itself.

Comment: Is that a protected field or property? If latter post the code.

Comment: A simple Label field which was auto-generated by the designer if one create a Label in the designer.

Comment: Sorry, No Idea. In my experience, if you are referring the property and that property causes recursion this will happen.

Comment: Your `question` is pretty much `unreadable` because of the `highlighting`. Please show an excerpt of the relevant code instead of writing three paragraphs about what it looks like. :)

Comment: Check the "Application" event log in the Windows event Viewer and look for the event that's written when an application crashes, you'll find two if Windows Error Reporting is turned on. One of these should contain a stacktrace. Please add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that some resources which are used in the `BaseUserControl` were deleted. Now I have added them again and it runs. But unfortunately I do not know how them were removed and why the `BaseUserControl` could be shown without any error in the designer but not the `DerivedUserControl`.